# Console.log(myState) shows full array, but Console.log(myState.length) gives 0

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am a beginner in React working on a Attendance-System Project.(Sorry for all the bad code)

So I have this component called ShowData, and it receives some props from it's parent component. I am using conditional rendering in this. So I have only one state variable called **filteredUsers**, and it's initialized to an empty array.

Now what I want to do is fetch all the User Data from firebase and once I have all the users, I set my state equal to that. So for that I have a **useEffect()**
which has this **async function called init()**

Now the problem is that, when I try to use filteredUsers.length in the conditional rendering part, it gives me 0.

```js
import React from "react";
import { db } from "./firebase";
import { dateStripper, getDaysArray } from "./utils";
import "./ShowData.css";
import MusterUser from "./MusterUser";

function ShowData(props) {
  let { userid, date, format, employee } = props;

  let [filteredUsers, setFilteredUsers] = React.useState([]);

  console.log(date);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    console.log("UseEffect triggered");

    async function getUserData(employeeID, currentDate) {
      let attendanceDoc = await db
        .collection(userid)
        .doc("Att-Records")
        .collection(currentDate)
        .doc(employeeID)
        .get()
        .then((doc) => {
          if (!doc.exists) {
            return { data: null, currentDate: currentDate };
          }
          return { data: doc.data(), currentDate: currentDate };
        });

      return attendanceDoc;
    }

    async function getEmployees() {
      return await db
        .collection(userid)
        .doc("Employee-Records")
        .collection("UUID-Data")
        .get()
        .then((employeeSnapshot) => {
          let temp = [];
          employeeSnapshot.forEach((employeeDoc) => {
            temp.push(employeeDoc);
          });
          return temp;
        });
    }

    async function init() {
      let allDates = [];
      let musterUsers = [];
      let dates = getDaysArray(date[0], date[1]);
      if (date[0] === date[1]) {
        dates.pop();
      }
      dates.forEach((date) => {
        allDates.push(dateStripper(date));
      });
      if (format === "muster" && employee === "all") {
        let serialNum = 0;

        let users = await getEmployees();

        users.forEach(async (user) => {
          serialNum = serialNum + 1;

          let tempUser = {
            SNo: serialNum,
            name: user.data()["Employee Name"],
            dept: user.data()["Employee Department"],
            desg: user.data()["Employee Designation"],
            total: 0,
            present: 0,
            absent: 0,
            miss: 0,
          };
          let calls = [];

          allDates.forEach(async (date) => {
            calls.push(getUserData(user.id, date));
          });

          let userPerDates = await Promise.all(calls);

          userPerDates.forEach((callbackResult) => {
            let data = callbackResult.data;
            let currentDate = callbackResult.currentDate;
            if (data) {
              tempUser["total"] = tempUser["total"] + 1;
              if (data["Status"] === "A") {
                tempUser[currentDate] = "Absent";
                tempUser["absent"] = tempUser["absent"] + 1;
              } else if (data["Status"] === "P") {
                tempUser[currentDate] = "Present";
                tempUser["present"] = tempUser["present"] + 1;
              } else if (data["Status"] === "MIS") {
                tempUser[currentDate] = "MIS";
                tempUser["miss"] = tempUser["miss"] + 1;
              }
            } else {
              tempUser[currentDate] = "N/A";
            }
          });
          musterUsers.push(tempUser);
        });
        return musterUsers;
      }
    }

    if (date.length) {
      console.log("init triggered");
      init().then((musterUsers) => {
        setFilteredUsers(musterUsers);
      });
    } else {
      console.log("not triggered");
    }
  }, [date, format, employee]);

  if (!date.length) {
    console.log("NoDate");
    return (
      <div className="noData">
        <h1>Nothing to show</h1>
      </div>
    );
  } else {
    console.log(filteredUsers);
    console.log(format);
    let allDates = [];
    let dates = getDaysArray(date[0], date[1]);
    if (date[0] === date[1]) {
      dates.pop();
    }
    dates.forEach((date) => {
      allDates.push(dateStripper(date));
    });
    console.log("I reached here");
    console.log(filteredUsers.length);
    if (format === "muster" && filteredUsers.length > 0) {
      console.log("Main function runs");
      return (
        <div className="data">
          <div className="data__header">
            <h1>Muster Roll</h1>
            <h1>
              From {allDates[0]} to {allDates[allDates.length - 1]}
            </h1>
          </div>
          <div className="data__box">
            <div className="data__columns">
              <li>Employee Name</li>
              <li>Employee Department</li>
              <li>Employee Designation</li>
              {allDates.map((allDates) => (
                <li className="dateColumn">{allDates}</li>
              ))}
              <li>Total</li>
              <li>Present</li>
              <li>Absent</li>
              <li>Miss</li>
            </div>
            <div className="muster__users">
              <MusterUser user={filteredUsers} />
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      );
    } else {
      return <h1>OOPS</h1>;
    }
  }
}

export default ShowData;
```

[image: See Array has these 3 elements but it still gives length 0, I am really confused what is happening.)]

Comment: Read this https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html

Answer (score 2):

Refer to the [Using the State Hook](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html)

```
const [myState, setMyState] = React.useState([]);

...

newArray = ["Hello", "World", "Know"]
setMyState(newArray)

...

React.useEffect(() => {
  console.log(myState)
}, [ myState ])
```

```
  ...
  return 
    (<div>
       {!date.length ? 
          <div className="noData">
            <h1>Nothing to show</h1>
          </div> :
          <div>
           ....
          </div>
       }
    </div>)
```

Comment: I tried this before, but the problem that I faced that whenever I did console.log(myState.length), it gives me 0, which is really weird.

Comment: you can't get the myState immediately after setMyState. instead, you need to get it using useEffect

Comment: I mean console.log(myState) prints the correct array, but myState.length shows 0.

Comment: No, the thing is I set my state in a useEffect, and then when it renders, I console.log two thing, the state array and its length, the state array shows up fine, but it’s length gives me 0, not the actual length.

Comment: can you update your question with the whole codebase?

Comment: your console log result is correct, filteredUsers is empty at first, but in chrome developer console, it looks 3 because it shows the value below was evaluated just now.

Comment: So how can I use my state in the conditional rendering part, I must ensure that it contains users, only then I would be able to render the data right?

Comment: and After I set my state inside useEffect, it must trigger a re-render, so won’t I be able to see the new updated value of my state in the final render?

Comment: first, check the result here, and see filteredState is logged everytime the value is updated. React.useEffect(() => {
  console.log(filteredState)
}, [ filteredState ])

Comment: also, instead of `if (!date.length)`, return immediately with the DOM elements, and if you need to check the conditions, you need to set them inside DOM.

Comment: I added (!date.length) so that for the first time, when no date is selected,  I could show "Nothing Here" to the user, how else would I achieve this?

Comment: console.log(filteredState) inside useEffect is logging correct array everytime I change the date range, but still the length gives 0.

Comment: Thankyou for the help, but still that .length thing is bugging me a lot.

Comment: let me know all the results for this `React.useEffect(() => { console.log(filteredState.length, "LENGTH") }, [ filteredState ]) `

Comment: I did as you mentioned above, and it returned 0 in both the cases, first when array was empty, it returned 0, and what's weird is after updating the state and populating my array, still it shows 0 inside the useEffect()

Answer (score 1):

instead of pushing elements one by one to the array, just use a temporary array and update it any number of times you want and then finally make your state equal to that array.